# processing data in parallel python

Tags: python-3.x, python-multiprocessing, python-multithreading

I have a script, parts of which at some time able to run in parallel. Python 3.6.6

The goal is to decrease execution time at maximum.

One of the parts is connection to Redis, getting the data for two keys, `pickle.loads` for each and returning processed objects.

What’s the best solution for such a tasks?
I’ve tried `Queue()` already, but `Queue.get_nowait()` locks the script, and after `{process}.join()` it also stops execution even though the task is done. Using `pool.map` raises `TypeError: can't pickle _thread.lock objects`.

All I could achieve is parallel running of all parts but still cannot connect the results

Answer (score 0):

`cPickle.load()` will release the GIL so you can use it in multiple threads easily. But `cPickle.loads()` will not, so don't use that.

Basically, put your data from Redis into a `StringIO` then `cPickle.load()` from there.  Do this in multiple threads using `concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor`.

Comment: You said `cPickle.load()` will release the GIL and also said that `cPickle.load()` will not.

Comment: so the suggestion is to pick `pool.map` for this case?

Comment: @AuroraWang: Sorry, fixed that, missed an `s`.

Comment: @Chickenfresh: You can use any of the ThreadPoolExecutor methods, map would be a fine choice.

Comment: as I know in python3 `_pickle` stands for your interpretation of `cPickle`, and If I put an object from Redis into `io.StringIO` it raises `TypeError: initial_value must be str or None, not bytes`

Comment: @Chickenfresh: If you have bytes you need BytesIO instead of StringIO.